# Did upstart or bash scripts change on Ubuntu 14.04? (Trying to boot sidekiq with upstart)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sidekiq, ubuntu-14.04, upstart

I'm fairly new to bash scripting, but it feel like I'm really missing something basic here. I'm trying to a barely modified version of [Mike Perham's upstart sidekiq script](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/upstart/manage-one/sidekiq.conf) on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, yet almost nothing is being evaluated as expected:

- export doesn't seem to be working
- source doesn't seem to evaluate my changed PATH variable in .bashrc or running the rbenv
  init command
- cd doesn't seem to change directories, unless the $(pwd) command isn't the correct way to evaluate it

Here's my modified script:

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.

# change to match your deployment user
setuid deploy
setgid deploy

stop on (stopping workers or runlevel [06])

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

instance $index

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash <<EOT
  # use syslog for logging
  # exec &> /dev/kmsg

  # pull in system rbenv
  export HOME=/home/deploy
  echo "home is $HOME"
  source /home/deploy/.bashrc
  echo "path is $PATH"

  cd /home/deploy/domain_freek/current
  echo "user is $(whoami) and pwd is $(pwd) and rbenv is located at $(which rbenv)"
  exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
EOT
end script
```

Here's the output I get in the upstart log file:

```
home is
path is /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
user is deploy and pwd is / and rbenv is located at 
/bin/bash: line 12: exec: bundle: not found
```

Comment: Try `exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'` (hard quotes around the marker). Output should make more sense.

Comment: Alright! Thanks, hard quotes helped. Now HOME is exported and cd actually changes the directory... Now I just gotta figure out how to properly load the .bashrc file, or initialize rbenv another way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

2 Changes made all the difference:

1) Add hard quotes to EOT in `exec /bin/bash << 'EOT'` (credit to Mat, thanks!)

2) Instead of loading .bashrc using source, add the rbenv lines from .bashrc directly to the upstart script. Replace `source /home/deploy/.bashrc` with:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

I have no idea why those two changes made the difference, and if that's related to a newer version of ubuntu, upstart, or bash. If anyone can explain, please chime in.

I've included my full working script for anyone just looking for the answer:

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Sidekiq instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/sidekiq.conf then mange sidekiq with:
#   sudo start sidekiq index=0
#   sudo stop sidekiq index=0
#   sudo status sidekiq index=0
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service sidekiq {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
stop on (stopping workers or runlevel [06])

# change to match your deployment user
setuid deploy
setgid deploy

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

# TERM is sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq.  Without declaring these as normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM

instance $index

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash << 'EOT'
  # use syslog for logging
  # exec &> /dev/kmsg

  # pull in system rbenv
  export HOME=/home/deploy
  echo "$HOME"
  #source /home/deploy/.bashrc
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
  echo "$PATH"

  cd /home/deploy/domain_freek/current
  echo "user is $(whoami) and pwd is $(pwd) and rbenv is located at $(which rbenv)"  
  exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
EOT
end script
```

Comment: Please submit a PR so we can get this fixed upstream!

Comment: I would use Upstart's ENV support directly:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#env
env HOME=/home/deploy

Comment: I wish it was possible to source .bashrc from inside the Upstart script. It's incredibly annoying to have to put env vars in two places when provisioning apps.

Comment: Just added a issue in sidekiq to update the script to fix this issue : https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2361

Answer (score 3):

The default `.bashrc` file on Ubuntu 14.04 has a couple lines to return immediately if the shell is running in non-interactive mode.  When you remove those lines from your bashrc then `source` will work as expected in upstart.

**~/.bashrc** (Lines to remove)

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm running 14.04.4 and the line I commented out of the .bashrc was `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. This allowed me to simply source the .bashrc in the upstart script. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Josh's solution didn't work for me on ubuntu 14.04 using rbenv. This however did work:

```
exec /bin/bash <<EOF
  export RBENV_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv
  export RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2
  cd /var/www/app/current
  exec /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec sidekiq -i ${index} -e production
EOF
```